# Is there a shortcut for `self.somevariable = somevariable` in a Python class constructor?

Tags: python, class, constructor

Constructors in Python often look like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b = None, c = defC):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b or []
        self.c = c
```

Is there a shortcut for this, e.g. to simply define `__init__(self,**kwargs)` and use the keys as properties of `self`?

Comment: I know one shouldn't have to have so many different parameters in a constructor that can't be logically collected in a dictionary, this question is more out of curiosity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem with

```
self.__dict__.update(locals())
```

is that it includes `self`, so you get `self.self`. It would be better to filter `self` out of `locals()`

eg.

```
vars(self).update((k,v) for k,v in vars().items() if k != 'self')
```

You can defend against accidentally overwriting methods with this variation

```
vars(self).update((k,v) for k,v in vars().items()
                   if k != 'self' and k not in vars(self))
```

If you don't want it to fail silently, you could also check beforehand like this

```
if any(k in vars(self) for k in vars()):
    raise blahblah
vars(self).update((k,v) for k,v in vars().items() if k != 'self')
```

Comment: Interesting point. So maybe something like `vars(self).update((k,v) for k,v in vars(self).items())` would make sure that only already existing properties can be set, and then use some code to warn (or even raise an exception) about the attempt to set a property that should not be set. Although I guess this would still allow to redefine class methods as [BrenBarn stated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12191118/321973)

Comment: @Tobias, I added an example to avoid overwriting class methods

Comment: Thanks! It's too early in the morning - I smiled when pronouncing `any(k` m-/ Ok, so with some slight modification one could even define default arguments. But this really indicates that one should stick to `self.var1 = var1` in most cases

Comment: @Tobias, yes usually explict is better. How else could you know to translate `None` into `[]` for `self.b`?

Comment: That alone is probably the shortest reason to not do this. Although some `for k in kwargs.keys()` and a keyword white-/blacklist and [`pop`ing from a copy of `**kwargs`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098577/321973) might provide some flexibility and remain readable in some way. But then again, I can't think of a real-life application of more than, say, ten named arguments of one constructor, where it wouldn't be more adequate to define different constructors using `@classmethod`...

Answer (score 9):

One idiom I've seen is `self.__dict__.update(locals())`.  If you run it right at the beginning of the method, this will update the object's dictionary with the arguments (since those are the only locals at the beginning of the method).  If you pass in `**kwargs` you can do `self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)`.

Of course, this is a fragile approach.  It can lead to puzzling bugs if you accidentally pass in an argument that masks an existing attribute.  For instance, if your class has a `.doSomething()` method and you accidentally pass `doSomething=1` to the constructor, it will override the method and cause an error later if you try to call that method.  For this reason it's better not to do this except in certain trivial cases (e.g., some sort of proxy object whose only purpose is to serve as a "bag" holding a few attributes).

Comment: I see, so I should avoid this in most circumstances, and then at least use some function that yields only the `**kwargs` that are already in `self.__dict__`. Related: [Is `self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)` good or poor style?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9728243/321973)

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Comment: It would work, but as [BrenBarn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12191118/321973) and [gnibbler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12191200/321973) suggest, there can be very inconvenient side-effects

Comment: No! The inconvenient side effect does only occur if you chose the `locals()` solution. It does not appear when using `**kwargs`!

Comment: True, I referring to the possibility to do something like `brokenInstance = SomeClass(a_method = [])` when `a_method` was a method previously defined in `SomeClass`, i.e. one could accidentally modify class properties that aren't supposed to be modified. Some whitelist or blacklist mechanism would need to be implement to prevent that