# Simplifying Init Method Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

Is there a better way of doing this?

```py
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.ServiceNo = kwargs["ServiceNo"]
        self.Operator = kwargs["Operator"]
        self.NextBus = kwargs["NextBus"]
        self.NextBus2 = kwargs["NextBus2"]
        self.NextBus3 = kwargs["NextBus3"]
```

The attributes (ServiceNo,Operator,...) always exist

Comment: Related: [Is there a shortcut for `self.somevariable = somevariable` in a Python class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12191075/674039) and [Is self.__dict__.update(**kwargs) good or poor style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9728243/674039)

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by "simpler".

For example, is what you wrote simpler than what I would write, namely

```
def __init__(self,ServiceNo, Operator, NextBus, NextBus2, NextBus3):
    self.ServiceNo = ServiceNo
    self.Operator = Operator
    self.NextBus = NextBus
    self.NextBus2 = NextBus2
    self.NextBus3 = NextBus3
```

True, I've repeated each attribute name an additional time, but I've made it much clearer which arguments are *legal* for `__init__`. The caller is not free to add any additional keyword argument they like, only to see it silently ignored.

Of course, there's a lot of boilerplate here; that's something a dataclass can address:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    ServiceNo: int
    Operator: str
    NextBus: Bus
    NextBus2: Bus
    NextBus3: Bus
```

(Adjust the types as necessary.)

Now each attribute is mentioned *once*, and you get the `__init__` method shown above for free.

Comment: Minor note: If you wish to force the arguments to be received by keyword to avoid a forward compatibility requirement to maintain order (a possible reason the OP received only as `**kwargs`), that's still possible with individually named arguments, you just change the `def` for `__init__` to: `def __init__(self, *, ServiceNo, Operator, NextBus, NextBus2, NextBus3):` (the `*` with no name prevents the arguments to its right from being received positionally).

Comment: I think I skipped mentioning that because I knew I'd be introducing dataclasses right away, and then you're back to positional arguments being accepted. I don't think there's anyway to make the dataclass generate an `__init__` that requires keyword-only arguments, but that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Better how? You don’t really describe what problem you’re trying to solve.

If it’s error handling, you can use the dictionary `.get()` method in the event that key doesn’t exist.

If you just want a more succinct way of initializing variables, you could remove the `**` and have the dictionary as a variable itself, then use it elsewhere in your code, but that depends on what your other methods are doing.

Answer (score -1):

A hacky solution available since the attributes and the argument names match exactly is to directly copy from the `kwargs` `dict` to the instance's `dict`, then check that you got all the keys you expected, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    vars(self).update(kwargs)
    if vars(self).keys() != {"ServiceNo", "Operator", "NextBus", "NextBus2", "NextBus3"}:
        raise TypeError(f"{type(self).__name__} missing required arguments")
```

I don't recommend this; [chepner's options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384871/364696) are all superior to this sort of hackery, and they're more reliable (for example, this solution fails if you use `__slots__` to prevent autovivication of attributes, as the instance won't having a backing `dict` you can pull with `vars`).