# Is it possible get a dictionary of passed in parameters similar to kwargs(python)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently creating an object like this:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        params = ['val1','val2','val3','val4',...]
        for p in params:
            setattr(self,p,kwargs.get(p,None))
```

I'm doing this so I don't have to do this:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val1=None,val2=None,val3=None,val4=None,...):
        self.val1=val1
        self.val2=val2
        self.val3=val3
        self.val4=val4
        ...
```

My question is, can you do a mix of the two? Where I can define the expected parameters yet still loop the parameters to set the attributes? I like the idea of defining the expected parameters because it is self documenting and other developers don't have to search for what kwargs are used.

I know it seems pretty petty but I'm creating an object from some XML so I'll be passing in many parameters, it just clutters the code and bugs me.

I did google this but couldn't find anything, probably because dictionary and kwargs together point to kwarg examples.

**UPDATE:** To be more specific, is it possible to get a dictionary of passed in parameters so **I don't have to use kwargs** at all?

Sudo code:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val1=None,val2=None,val3=None,val4=None,...):
        for k,v in dictionary_of_paramters.iteritems():
            setattr(self,k,v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect

def myargs(val1, val2, val3=None, val4=5):
        print inspect.currentframe().f_locals
```

it shows all the locals available on the current stack frame.

```
myargs('a','b')
==>  {'val3': None, 'val2': 'b', 'val1': 'a', 'val4': 5}
```

(note: it's not guaranteed to be implemented on all Python interpreters)

**edit**: i concur that it's not a pretty solution.  what i would do is more like:

```
def _yourargs(*names):
        "returns a dict with your named local vars"
        alllocs = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals
        return {n:alllocs[n] for n in names}

def askformine(val1, val2, val3=None, val4=5):
        "example to show just those args i'm interested in"
        print _yourargs('val1','val2','val3','val4')

class Obj(object):
        "example inserting some named args as instance attributes"
        def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=4):
                 self.__dict__.update(_yourargs('arg1','arg2'))
```

**edit2** slightly better:

```
def pickdict(d,*names):
    "picks some values from a dict"
    return {n:d[n] for n in names}

class Obj(object):
    "example inserting some named args as instance attributes"
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=4):
        self.__dict__.update(pickdict(locals(),'arg1','arg2'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for. From my understanding it should work with all pure python interpreters, just not things like jython, etc...correct?

Comment: Ugh, are you sure this is worth it?  Keep in mind, f_locals will have more than just the arguments, and this will make your code odd and magical.  Just spell out the arguments you need.

Comment: odd and magical... you can encapsulate in a function to hide the ugliness.  more than the args: you can call your utility function with a list of var names you're interested in.  worth it? i don't think so.

Comment: @rjbez: it's the same thing... i had totally forgot about `locals()`.  shows how little i like about this :-)

Comment: @NedBatchelder Ok thanks, you guys convinced me it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no nice way to get a dictionary of all the arguments to a function.  The `**kwargs` syntax only collects up the extra keyword arguments, not the ones that match explicit parameters in the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Although you won't be able to get the parameters without using kwargs or the inspect module (see other answers), you can do something like this...

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
```

Every object has a dictionary that stores all of the attributes, which you can access via `self.__dict__`. Then you're just using [update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to set all of the attributes in that object's internal dictionary.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728243/is-self-dict-updatekwargs-good-or-poor-style) on some discussion of this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain the args dict at the very top of your method, before you define any locals, this is as simple as:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val1=None,val2=None,val3=None,val4=None):
       kwargs = dict(locals())
```

To read this dict later on, some introspection magic is required:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val1=None,val2=None,val3=None,val4=None):

       # feel free to add more locals

       loc = dict(locals())
       fun = sys._getframe().f_code
       kwargs = {x:loc[x] for x in fun.co_varnames[:fun.co_argcount]}
```

You can also make the latter reusable by adding a function like this:

```
def getargs():
    f = sys._getframe(1)
    return {x:f.f_locals[x] for x in f.f_code.co_varnames[:f.f_code.co_argcount]}
```

and then:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val1=None,val2=None,val3=None,val4=None):

       # feel free to add more locals

       kwargs = getargs()
```

This is cpython-specific, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mix the two.
See below:

```
def method(a, b=1, *args, **kwargs):
    '''some code'''
```

This is valid. Here:

```
'a' is a required argument
'b' is a default argument
'args' will have all the non-keyword arguments and
'kwargs' will have all the keyword arguments.
```

Example:

```
method(1,2,3,4,5,test=6,test1=7)
```

This call will have:

```
a=1
b=2
args=(3,4,5)
kwargs={'test':6,'test1':7}
```

Answer (score 0):

A kind of an ugly workaround: Inject extra arguments into kwargs and use it where you want to loop over all keyword arguments (PS this is an example usage of the inspect module, but *not* recommended for production use):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import inspect

def inject_defaults(func):
    """ injects '__defaults' key into into kwargs, 
        so it can be merged with kwargs in the decorated method """

    args, varargs, varkwargs, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    have_defaults = args[-len(defaults):]
    defaults_dict = dict(zip(have_defaults, defaults))

    def fun(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['__defaults'] = defaults_dict
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return fun

@inject_defaults
def f1(a,b,c, x=1, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update(kwargs['__defaults'])
    del kwargs['__defaults']

    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        # here, x, y and z will appear
        print(k, v)

f1(1, 2, 3, y=3, z=2)
# prints
# ('y', 3)
# ('x', 1)
# ('z', 2)
```