# What does self.__dict__.update(fields) do?

Tags: python

Say I have this code:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, **fields):
        self.__dict__.update(fields)


class A(B):
    def __init__(self, **fields):
        super().__init__(**fields)
```

What is going on here? Why are updating the `__dict__` of `B` in this way?

So if we instantiated `A(c=1, d=2)`, what happens?

Comment: Is `ABC` referrring to `abc.ABC` in metaclasses? It updates every keyword argument in the dictionary as an attribute of an instance, so `a.__dict__ = {'c': 1, 'd': 2}`

Comment: It sets instance attributes for each keyword argument.  Also: it's ugly and bad, don't use it.

Comment: [Is self.__dict__.update(**kwargs) good or poor style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9728243/674039)

Comment: if one of you writes a full answer, I'll give credit!

Comment: I added the answer by wim as a dupe, since it already addresses what's happening here, which is what the question is about